# Mistake on Josekipedia after probe & invasion on keima shimari?

Tags: go, joseki

I have found a possible problem in this joseki, see josekipedia:

http://www.josekipedia.com/#path:qdttocrdreqcpdpbrcrbsdobnbncmcndmbpcodsb

[image]

They comment this white's move as "Makes life". But it seems to me that white is dead actually - what about this sequence?

```
$$c Black kills white?
$$ ---------
$$ ...3412.-
$$ .XXOO5OO-
$$ .XOXOOX.-
$$ ..OXXX.X-
$$ ......X.-
$$ ........-
```

So that T18 move seems like a big mistake. White perhaps should have played R19 instead and go to a ko fight?

So is there a mistake on josekipedia or did I miss something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

White Q19 is a mistake.  The correct move is R18.  Then Black can't connect at Q19 because the stones would still be in atari.

```
$$c White survives!
$$ ---------
$$ ..63512.-
$$ .XXOO4OO-
$$ .XOXOOX.-
$$ ..OXXX.X-
$$ ......X.-
$$ ........-
```

After the capture, **a** and **b** are [miai](https://senseis.xmp.net/?Miai) to make White a second eye.

```
$$c Resistance is futile!
$$ ---------
$$ ..Oab.O.-
$$ .XXOOOOO-
$$ .XOXOOX.-
$$ ..OXXX.X-
$$ ......X.-
$$ ........-
```

Comment: and taking 3 stones yields an eye (it s important to add, as if there was only 2 it could be a false eye)

Comment: Sometimes even taking three gives a false eye.